# Perl: safe eval?

Tags: perl, eval

I'm curious if there is any good information on performing restricted evals.

Looking at the docs, there is a `use Safe` that has a `reval` method, but I'm not sure how safe that is.

What I want to do is to be able to pass various conditional statements as a string to a function w/o the source abusing the eval.

For instance:

```
sub foo {
   my $stmt = shift;
   my $a    = 3;
   say eval($stmt)?"correct":"wrong") , "($stmt)";
}

foo( q{1  == $a} );
foo( q{$a =~ /3/ );
foo( q{(sub {return 3})->() eq 3}  );
```

Would `use Safe` be good for this?  All I need to be able to do is comparisons, no disk access, or variable manipulations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [indicated in the docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval.html), `eval($stmt)` evaluates `$stmt` "in the lexical context of the current Perl program, so that any variable settings or subroutine and format definitions remain afterwards." This is useful for delaying execution of `$stmt` until runtime.

If you `reval($stmt)` in a [Safe](http://search.cpan.org/~rgarcia/Safe-2.30/Safe.pm) compartment, essentially the same thing happens, the statement is eval'd, but it's eval'd in a new lexical context which can only see the Safe compartment's namespace, and in which you can control what sorts of operators are allowed.

So, yes, if you declare a Safe compartment and `reval($stmt)` in that compartment, then (a) execution of `$stmt` won't change the functioning of your program without your consent (I guess this is what you mean by "w/o the source abusing the eval"). And, (b) yes, `$stmt` won't be able to access the disk without your consent if you `reval($stmt)`.  In (a) "your consent" requires explicitly playing with the symbol table, and in (b) "your consent" would require specifying a set of [op codes](http://search.cpan.org/~rgarcia/Safe-2.30/Safe.pm) that would allow disk access.

I'm not really sure how safe this is either.  However, you can see it in action if you set it up and step through it in the debugger.

Comment: Jason, thx.  What I meant by `abusing the eval` is injecting code to do something destructive.  Eval should be handled with care, but in this case I'm creating a module that would use it, so whatever I could do to make it more secure would be helpful.  I have to believe that codepad.org is using some form of veal and if you try `print \`ls -l\`;` you get `Disallowed system call: SYS_pipe`

Comment: yep, this is exactly what reval can do for you. We use it in our application which essentially has a mini-programming environment. Also, the config files directly contain perl data strutures, so we also use it to make sure there is nothing funny going there before allowing the config files to modify the environment.

Comment: Thanks Jason, do you know if the anonymous subroutine call (my last example) would still be able to run?